# How to compare two dataframes and filter rows and columns where a difference is found

Tags: python, pandas, equality

I am testing dataframes for equality.

```
df_diff=(df1!=df2)
```

I get `df_diff` which is same shape as `df*`, and contains boolean `True/False`.

Now I would like to keep only the columns and rows of `df1` where there was at least a different value.
If I simply do

```
   df1=[df_diff.values]
```

I get all the **rows** where there was at least one `True` in `df_diff`, but lots of columns originally had `False` only.

As a second step, I would like then to be able to replace all the values (element-wise in the dataframe) which were equal (where `df_diff==False`) with `NaNs`.

example:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
df2=pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,99,3],[4,5,99],[7,8,9]])
```

I would like to get from `df1`

```
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

to

```
    1  2
0  2  NaN  
1  NaN  6
```

Comment: Can you add data sample? Do you need all rows where at least one `False` ?

Comment: will add an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check at least one `True` per rows of columns:

```
df = df_diff[df_diff.any(axis=1)]
```

It is possible to filter both of the original dataframes like so:

```
df11 = df1[df_diff.any(axis=1)]
df22 = df2[df_diff.any(axis=1)]
```

If want all columns and rows:

```
df = df_diff.loc[df_diff.any(axis=1), df_diff.any()]
```

EDIT: Filter `d1` and add `NaN`s by [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df_diff=(df1!=df2)

m1 = df_diff.any(axis=1)
m2 = df_diff.any()

out = df1.loc[m1, m2].where(df_diff.loc[m1, m2])
print (out)
     1    2
0  2.0  NaN
1  NaN  6.0
```

Comment: great as always